# Do I misunderstand histogram?

Tags: image-processing

If I have an grayscale image , intensity is in range [0,255]. Should I understand that the histogram of any intensity value is the number of pixels that have intensity value?

Thank you very much.

Comment: That depends on how the intensity values are measured. Pixels? Percent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intensity histogram will give the number of pixels that have the intensity value. Thus, the graph will consist of 256 numbers and the distribution of all the pixels will be depicted on the graph(basically the count)!